# What is the use of static doing in this code sample?

Tags: java, oop, static

I'm working on a basic webapp tutorial using jqGrid, a plugin for jquery that just presents data in a grid. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.sunilgulabani.com/2013/06/jqgrid-example-with-java.html) and I don't understand what's happening on the lines following the declaration of my `data` Map.

```
public class Data {

private static Map<String, List<Person>> data = new HashMap<String, List<Person>>();

static
{
    populateBS217RHData();
    poplateBS18QTData();
}

public List<Person> getData(String postcode)
{
    return data.get(postcode.toUpperCase());        
}

private static void populateBS217RHData()
{
    // do thing
}

private static void poplateBS18QTData()
{
    // do other thing
}
```

}

I understand the purpose of the static keyword is to make methods / properties available without instantiating the class, but I don't really "get" what it's doing in this context.

I have lots of experience with .NET but next to none with Java so I'm not really sure what's going on here. Is there a special name for this syntax / use?

Comment: Search for ["Static Initialization Block"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Comment: If having to use static (at all), I would have written it like: `private static Map<String, List<Person>> data = AStaticMethodThatLoadsTheData();`. Note how this change (with the simple removal of a single `static`) now allows for Dependency Injection and non-static usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a static initializer, and as [per the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7), it is ...

> ... executed when the class is initialized.

They are usually used to initialize `static` fields (known as *class variables*) from a non-trivial multi-line expression. This is simply as a single static function call or variable assignment can be done on the same line as the field declaration resulting in far fewer lines of code.

The [Java Tutorials > Initializing Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) also talks about it:

> A static initialization block is a normal block of code enclosed in braces, { }, and preceded by the static keyword

A single class can have one or more of these. They are called in "left to right" order (i.e. the order of declaration in the class body).

You can also declare "instance initialization" blocks, which are similar, but not preceded by the `static` keyword - they run every time a class is instantiated.

Initialization blocks can be tricky if you declare fields *after* the block. There are rules about reading and writing to fields in initialization blocks which depend on declaration order of the field and block.

It is, frankly, simpler to declare fields first, and if you must use an initialization block then do that afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

```
static
{
    populateBS217RHData();
    poplateBS18QTData();
}
```

This is a **static block**

*Static blocks* are also called **Static initialization blocks** . A static initialization block is a normal block of code enclosed in braces, { }, and preceded by the static keyword. Static blocks are executed when **JVM** loads the class.

A class can have any number of static initialization blocks, and they can appear anywhere in the class body. The runtime system guarantees that static initialization blocks are called in the order that they appear in the source code.

- If you have executable statements in the static block, JVM will
  automatically execute these statements when the class is loaded into
  JVM.

Answer (score 1):

```
static
{
    populateBS217RHData();
    poplateBS18QTData();
}
```

Here this is `static` **initialization block** . The code placed between the curly braces of **static initialization block** will be executed only once for the residing class even though the class object is created multiple times.

In `java` there is a another **initialization block** which is called - **instance initialization block** where the `static` keyword is not present. The **instance initialization block** will be executed for the each `object/instance` of the class. It is like other instance member of a class.